# Office 2013 Web Apps - Standalone redistributable document

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-2013

Please consider a case as show in the image below...

[image]

I have two different apps (content + navigation) in a same excel sheet that are able to communicate with each other,

Based on this scenario, following are some questions...

1- Is it possible to deliver an excel document (standalone) which contains both of these apps, so that the end user doesn't need to insert these apps from the ribbon toolbar and user could be able to use this document on any machine (without any configurations and involving the app store/network)?

2- Is it possible to automate the process of generating excel documents that contains both of these apps? My purpose of doing this automation is to change the data contained in excel sheets, and user can perform analysis with his data.

### Thanks!

Asif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on msdn forums and got some feedback by them, you may follow the link below for details...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/057723f1-cfe5-4f41-9d7a-430cb2f0c4c6/create-a-distributable-excel-document-with-web-apps?forum=appsforoffice&prof=required

Based on these details, my understanding is that Office 2013 web apps don't currently support standalone deployments packaged with local html files. But in future they might think of providing support for disconnected mode web apps in Office 2013.

Your comments are welcome!

Thanks,
Asif